# What does the word "recognize" mean in this sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

URL: https://www.nytimes.com/aponline/2019/02/05/us/ap-us-state-of-union-text.html

> This year, America will **recognize** two important anniversaries that show us the majesty of America's mission and the power of American pride.

What does it mean by *recognize an anniversary*? I looked the word up in dictionary but still can't understand. I don't know which meaning can be used here. Hope someone can give me some help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [sense 6 in Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/recognize):

> 6. To show appreciation of.
>
> *to **recognize** services by a testimonial*

I would paraphrase it also as "to give due credit to". We will recognize these anniversaries by holding official events, inviting participants and members of their families, making speeches, making TV documentaries etc.